# Using .. and . to copy files from dirctories

Tags: directory, file-copy, programming

I'm trying to copy a file from the home directory to the current directory( which is a subdirectory of a directory in home) using  .. and . instead of path names or ~

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

> cd ..
>
> cd ..
>
> cp file .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without using path names? This will only be possible if you are in a subdir of $HOME, since you can't go deeper without a directory name. There is not enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: It still doesn't make any sense, even after the update. Are you trying to say that you know that $HOME is two levels back and "file" is your current working directory?

Comment: The file I'm trying to copy is in $HOME and I want to copy it to the current directory with is two levels back.

Comment: `cp ../../file .`?

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't very clear, but I'll assume your present working directory is

```
$HOME/level1/level2/
```

And there is a file in ~/HOME/ that you want to copy.

```
cp ../../file    ./
```

Which in English reads as: copy from up_a_level/up_another_level/filename to current_directory

Answer (score 0):

let's say the name of the subdirectory in your home is `abc`. and the name of the file inside your home directory is `123`. then you have to do the following

```
~# cd abc
~# cp ../123 .
```

the expression '..' means the upper directory from the current. the expression '.' means the current directory. so you first `cd` into the subdirectory, and then copy the file from the upper directory to the current.